# Bullets Shooting Only One Direction

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I am making a 2D platformer with Unity and I have run into a small problem. I have enemies that shoot bullets at the player. However, the bullets are only shooting in one direction regardless of which direction the enemy is facing.

In my Enemy Script I have this:

```
Instantiate(bullet, spawnPosition.position, Quaternion.identity);
```

and in my bullet script I have this

```
rigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector2(bulletSpeed,0);
```

Please help if you can.
I understand why this is happening, but I can not figure out a solution. To update my question I want to be able to check the enemies direction so that I can change the bullet speed to positive/negative to match the direction. Since there will be multiple enemies of this type I do not know how to do this.

```
public class bulletScript : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    private float bulletSpeed;
    GameObject parent;

    private Vector3 theScale;

    void Start () {

        rigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector2(bulletSpeed,0);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    //  if(transform.localScale.x < 0) bulletSpeed = -100;
    //  if(transform.localScale.x > 0) bulletSpeed = 100;
    }
    public void SetEnemy(GameObject obj)
    {
        parent = obj;
    }
```

Then in HammerScript.cs

```
    public class HammerScript : MonoBehaviour {


    public bulletScript bullet;
    public Transform spawnPosition;


    void FixedUpdate () 
    {

        instantiate(bullet, spawnPosition.position, Quaternion.identity);
        ((bulletScript)bullet).SetEnemy(this);                  
    }




    }
```

2 new errors:
1-Assets/Scripts/Level 2/HammerScript.cs(89,64): error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for `bulletScript.SetEnemy(UnityEngine.GameObject)' has some invalid arguments
2-Assets/Scripts/Level 2/HammerScript.cs(89,64): error CS1503: Argument`#1' cannot convert `HammerScript' expression to type`UnityEngine.GameObject'

Comment: Please show the entire relevant sections of code (including the class declaration).

Comment: I am now getting this error : Assets/Scripts/Level 2/HammerScript.cs(88,48): error CS1061: Type `UnityEngine.GameObject' does not contain a definition for `SetEnemy' and no extension method `SetEnemy' of type `UnityEngine.GameObject' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: You should change `Enemy parent;` to `GameObject parent;`.

Comment: Please check my answer again. You need to cast `bullet` to a `bulletScript`.

Comment: What is the new error?

Comment: Assets/Scripts/Level 2/HammerScript.cs(88,56): error CS0030: Cannot convert type `UnityEngine.GameObject' to `bulletScript'

Comment: I got some new errors

Answer (score 2):

`the bullets are only shooting in one direction regardless of which direction the enemy is facing.`

Well, unless `bulletSpeed` is positive or negative depending on the enemy's direction, every bullet will have the same speed and direction. In your code, the bullets' velocities do not depend on the enemies' directions at all.

What you could do is keep a reference in the bullet to the enemy that it came from, and then set the velocity according to that enemy's info.

You can do that by having a `SetEnemy` method that takes an `Enemy` as a parameter in your `Bullet` class, and then you can just call `((bulletScript)bullet).SetEnemy(this);` immediately after the `Instantiate` call.

So your `HammerScript` file should look like this:

```
public class HammerScript : MonoBehaviour
{
   public bulletScript bullet;
   public Transform spawnPosition;

   void FixedUpdate () 
   {
       instantiate(bullet, spawnPosition.position, Quaternion.identity);
       ((bulletScript)bullet).SetEnemy(this);                  
   }
}
```

Then, in your `Bullet` class you can have the following:

```
class bulletScript : MonoBehavior
{
    GameObject parent;
    public void SetEnemy(GameObject obj)
    {
        parent = e;
    }

    // ... whatever else you have, including the method that sets the velocity
}
```

Then in your bullet script you would set `rigidbody2D.velocity` to something that has to do with the enemy (which would be `this.parent`).

Comment: How would I keep a reference of the enemy that created it? I dont want to get it confused with multiple enemies of the same type

Comment: This sounds like it would work however I am not sure on how to reference the original object that created the bullet.

Comment: Im still a bit new to this so Im not totally sure what you mean by creating a SetEnemy method.

Comment: Thank you! I am getting an error however in the enemy script when I use bullet.SetEnemy(this)

Comment: Im also getting an error when I try to type Enemy parent and (Enemy e)

Comment: @user1569940 Please post the code to both your `Enemy` and `Bullet` scripts.

Comment: Enemy could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference

Comment: @user1569940 _What is the error?_ Please post _all_ of the code in your question and state what errors you are receiving.

Answer (score 0):

Your current implementation only allow the bullet to go into one direction. Let's assume your bulletSpeed is always positive.

If you consider another direction with the angle `alpha` from that base direction, then you need to create a rotated Vector, which you can do like this:

```
new Vector2(bulletSpeed * Mathf.Cos(alpha), bulletSpeed * Mathf.Sin(alpha));
```

---

Also consider that `alpha` has to be given as radians, if you truly want to use degrees calculate the radians first:

```
alpha = (degrees / 180) * 90
```